# App crashes when entering in screen React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm making a mobile app and then suddenly when I enter this Screen the whole app crashes. It was working before but, after I changed some style, it gave me some errors about too much Call Stack but stopped saying that and just crashes. I really don't know what's causing this. I tried to see if there was on the UseEffect() I think there is nothing there causing this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext} from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
    AsyncStorage,
    Dimensions,
    Image,
    Alert,
} from "react-native";
import PlusImage from "../../../../assets/add_circle-24px.png";
import mainContext from "../../../services/contexts/mainContext";
import listContext from "../../../services/contexts/listContext";
import taskContext from "../../../services/contexts/taskContext";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import styles from "./styles";
import TaskItem from "../../utils/TaskItem";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function List({ route, navigation }) {
    const {
        clean,
        getTasksList,
        edited,
        toogleEdited,
        deleteList,
        doneTasks,
        todoTasks,
    } = useContext(listContext);
    const { taskEdited, idtask, deleteTask } = useContext(taskContext);
    const [listName, setListName] = useState("");
    const [screenTasks, setScreenTasks] = useState([{}]);
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false);

    const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").height);

    async function getListName() {
        setListName(await AsyncStorage.getItem("listName"));
    }
    async function asyncGetTasks() {
        await getTasksList();
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (listName) getListName();
        asyncGetTasks();
        setScreenTasks(done ? doneTasks : todoTasks);
        if (idtask) {
            navigation.navigate("Task");
        }
    }, [edited, taskEdited, idtask, done]);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar hidden />
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.goBack();
                        clean();
                    }}
                >
                    <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        Alert.alert(
                            "Are you sure you want to delete this list?",
                            "",
                            [
                                {
                                    text: "Cancel",
                                    style: "cancel",
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "OK",
                                    onPress: () => {
                                        deleteList();
                                        clean();
                                        navigation.goBack();
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                            { cancelable: true }
                        );
                    }}
                >
                    <MaterialIcons name="delete" size={32} color="#bc0000" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.titleContent}>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>{listName}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.midButtonsContainer}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        opacity: 1,
                        backgroundColor: done ? null : "#dddddd",
                        borderRadius: 7,
                        padding: 8,
                        opacity: 1,
                    }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                            setDone(false);
                            toogleEdited();
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>To do</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        opacity: 1,
                        backgroundColor: done ? "#dddddd" : null,
                        borderRadius: 7,
                        padding: 8,
                        opacity: 1,
                    }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                            setDone(true);
                            toogleEdited();
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.doneButton}>Done</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
            {screenTasks.length > 0 ? (
                <FlatList
                    data={screenTasks}
                    renderItem={(item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <TaskItem
                                OnSwipeRight={() => deleteTask(item.item._id)}
                                {...{ item }}
                            />
                        );
                    }}
                />
            ) : (
                <View style={styles.emptyContent}>
                    <Text style={styles.emptyText}>This list don't have tasks yet</Text>
                </View>
            )}

            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: screenHeight - 120,
                    right: 28,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    width: 50,
                    alignSelf: "flex-end",
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("NewTask");
                }}
            >
                <Image source={PlusImage} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you're testing using android, sometimes you can open up android studio and the logcat tab will give you more information. I don't know if there's an xcode equivelent

Comment: @Sam sorry but im programming in an iOS but in a windows pc

Comment: How did you solve it? Even I'm getting a crash on a simple useEffect.

Comment: @YM honestly I don't remember how I solved this. This is a project that I don't touch since 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import it from the react lib?

`import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`

I don't see it in your import above.

Comment: I am importing it  but didn't put it in here, I am changing that